# Error! Unknown op code for conditional

Tags: mailmerge, aspose.words

I am using Aspose.Words to do the MailMerge. But after merge for a merge field, It is showing **Error! Unknown op code for conditional** in document itself.  This error may be due to incorrectly formed merged field.  But my requirement is to detect/catch such error through code. Because, in our case user themselves creates the word template and upload into system.  I have written very simple code to read do the mail merge.

```
doc.MailMerge.Execute(this.DataSource.Rows[rowIndex];
```

Can we detect such error in code?  I tried to find online, but nothing useful could find.

Comment: Is there any detail in the InnerException? It would be helpful if you post a sample Word document to reproduce the issue.

Comment: It is not throwing in any exception and completing merge.  But in place of ill-formed merged field, it is replacing with above error message.

Comment: I am wondering, if I can catch such exception/error.

Comment: I could not find any way to make Aspose throw any exception, but there is a workaround to catch this. See the sample code in the answer

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No exception will be thrown in this scenario, but you can catch using the result of field after merging. Try the below sample code

```
// Load the document
Aspose.Words.Document doc = new Aspose.Words.Document(src);
// Do processing and mail merge etc

// Select all field start nodes so we can find the merge fields.
NodeCollection fieldStarts = doc.GetChildNodes(NodeType.FieldStart, true);
foreach (FieldStart fieldStart in fieldStarts)
{
    // Get the next sibling
    Run fieldResult = (Run)fieldStart.NextSibling;

    // Match the error code with the result
    if (fieldResult.NextSibling.NextSibling.GetText().Equals("Error! Unknown op code for conditional.", StringComparison.CurrentCultureIgnoreCase))
    {
        // Find the page number, where the field is present
        LayoutCollector collector = new LayoutCollector(doc);
        int pageNumber = collector.GetStartPageIndex(fieldStart);
        Console.WriteLine("Error in field at Page: " + pageNumber + ". Field text: " + fieldResult.GetText());
    }
}
```

Comment: I Think problem happening when Field update happening during merge.  {IF<<Primary_address_state>> "," ""} is causing above error.  Field is not empty in datasource.  Can we Identify which field block is causing this error.

Comment: The if condition gives you the reference to the field in the document. You can find out the page number on which it is located. See the updated answer.

Comment: Thanks for workaround.  I will open ticket with ASPOSE on this issue.